# Why does changing the order of 'it' and 'subject' in RSpec change my test result?

Tags: ruby, rspec

The class being tested `qa.rb` contains the code:

```
class QA
  def initialize(bugs: 0)
    @bugs = bugs
  end

  def speak
    "Hello!"
  end

  def happy?
    @bugs > 0
  end

  def debug
    @bugs = 0
  end
end
```

The RSpec file `qa_spec.rb` contains the code:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'qa'

RSpec.describe QA do
  describe '#happy?' do
    context 'when bugs are more than 0' do
      it 'returns true' do
        subject { described_class.new(bugs: 1) }
        expect(subject).to be_happy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails when I run it, and gives me this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Jobla\repos\TDD> rspec qa_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) QA#happy? when bugs are more than 0 returns true
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to be_happy
       expected `#<QA:0x2e0d640 @bugs=0>.happy?` to return true, got false
     # ./qa_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02999 seconds (files took 0.16995 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./qa_spec.rb:7 # QA#happy? when bugs are more than 0 returns true
```

However, when I edit `qa_spec.rb` and I swap the `it` and `subject` lines, the test suddenly passes:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'qa'

RSpec.describe QA do
  describe '#happy?' do
    context 'when bugs are more than 0' do      
      subject { described_class.new(bugs: 1) }  #swapped with line below 
      it 'returns true' do                      #swapped with line above
        expect(subject).to be_happy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Tests pass:

```
PS C:\Users\Jobla\repos\TDD> rspec qa_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.01003 seconds (files took 0.17993 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Please could someone explain **why does swapping the `it` and `subject` lines change the result of the test?**

Comment: Calling `subject` outside the example _defines_ the subject, whereas calling `subject` within the example _retrieves_ it. RSpec should probably output a warning when passing a block to the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subject` is designed to be set in `context` or `describe` block, but not in `it`.
If you do not set `subject` before `it` then `subject` would be set automatically by calling `new` without parameters on `described_class`. `bugs` will be set to default `0`. After that, you call it with a block `subject { described_class.new(bugs: 1) }` inside `it`, it's the same as if you call `described_class.new { described_class.new(bugs: 1) }` because `subject` inside `it` is an instance of `QA` class.